# Nvm installation using bash script

Tags: bash, nvm

I am trying to install nvm using a script but every time the installation process completes, I get the error **nvm command not found**. Same steps are working on the terminal.

```
#!/bin/sh

installNVM() {
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential libssl-dev 
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" # This loads nvm bash_completion

. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

. $HOME/.profile

}
```

Comment: Obvious question: Did you bother to put the directory, where `nvm` resides, into your PATH?

Comment: Do you run this as a script, or do you source it and then run the function?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour], read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @BenjaminW.  I am running this as a script

Comment: @user1934428  The steps for nvm installtion are working on terminal but not using a script after running the script I have to run source ~/.profile after which it starts running .I am following the same nvm steps given in documentation .

Comment: If this is the complete script, then running it declares a function which is never called and then disappears because it was declared in a subshell.

Comment: @ashutoshpathania : I did not say you should check the PATH in the terminal. Of course you have to check it at that place where you are running the script, i.e. inside the script, right before running nvm.